# open files(pdf,word,excel) in php(mysql database is used)

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to php and mysql.i have created a php page for uploading files and these files are saved to my local drive.In another page when a user selects a option files relating to the option are displayed in table format.one column will be link to the file in local drive.upto here i was successful.
Problem is that when clicking on the file hyperlink nothing is displayed.but when i copy address link of the file and paste in new window it is opening.please help me I am stuck for 2 weeks with problem.
To experiment I Have created simple php file just to see the hyperlink working.but no success.I will paste here the trails i have used

```
<?php echo "<a href=`file:///C|/Inetpub/wwwroot/help.gif' >hi</a>";?>-----not worked
<?php echo "<a href=http://www.google.com>hi</a>";?> ------ working.
```

even " "  tags are not working if files are saved as php file.....i am using ISp server.my php files are saved in "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\phpsample" path
please help me find solution

----my original code----

```
<form  action="http://localhost/phpsample/upload/upload2.php" method='post'enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Instrument:<select name="flist">
  <option>select</option> 
  <option>gt1</option>
  <option>gt2</option>
  <option>gt3</option>
  <option>gt4</option>
</select>
</br>
Date: <input type="date" name="fdate" /></br>
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php


global $dest;
global $name;

$dest='E:\divya';
$name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo $dest;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"$dest/$name");

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("upload_db", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload_tb (Instrument, date_upload, filename)
VALUES('$_POST[flist]','$_POST[fdate]','$name')");
mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

----my original code to download file from table----

```
<form  action="http://localhost/phpsample/display/display.php" method='post'enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Instrument:
  <select name="flist">
    <option>select</option>
    <option>gt1</option>
    <option>gt2</option>
    <option>gt3</option>
    <option>gt4</option>
  </select>
</br>
Date: 
<input type="date" name="fdate" /></br>

<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php

echo $_POST['fdate'];
echo $_POST['flist'];

$path='file:\\\C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\phpsample\\display\\NewTextDocument.txt';


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("upload_db", $con);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload_tb  WHERE Instrument='$_POST[flist]'");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Slno</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>comment</th>
</tr>";
fopen("c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\phpsample\display\NewTextDocument.txt","r");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $filename=$row['filename'];
echo $filename;
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Instrument'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date_upload'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"."<a href= $path>". $row['filename'] ."</a>"."</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should be pretty obvious - when your link says "open file C:/stuff/stuff.txt", the user's browser will attempt to find a file at this location on *their* computer...

Comment: You just want how to read write on file using php

Comment: @dcoder:.at present i am using my system.i am trying to access file stored on the laptop i am working.it stil nt working.

Comment: @learner i want to open my saved files like excel,word etc.just like opening file in a powerpoint using hyperlink.i want this same function using php

Answer (score 1):

Put this script into download.php in the same folder as upload2.php, and invoke it as

```
http://localhost/phpsample/upload/download.php?file=FILE
```

where `FILE` is the filename that was uploaded.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "upload_db");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

$name = $_GET['file'];
$query_filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $name);

$src = 'E:\divya';

$data = mysqli_query($con, "select filename from upload_tb where filename = '$query_filename'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($data) ! 1) die ('File not uploaded: ' . htmlentities($name));

$path = "$src/$name";
http_send_content_disposition($name);
$type = mime_content_type($path);
http_send_content_type($type);
http_send_file($path);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I should remind you that you need to validate the filename. You don't want your server to let people download any file from your system. You should limit it to a public directory.

Comment: actually requiremnt is that users will upload files to a common folder which is there on a common system.on another webpage files are displayed.any one who visits this page need to open this file.this will be there only on our local network(intranet).as i already said everything else is working fine except this opening of file when clicked on hyperlink.

Comment: @barmar.i have tried the code.its working fine for pdf.but not for images or word.please provide me with full working code for to open files through hyperlink.thank you very much in advance..

Comment: What isn't working? Is it not downloading the file, or is it downloading as the wrong type? If the latter, see the documentation of mime_content_type, maybe there's some configuration you need to update.

Comment: it is downloading file.but downloaded file is blank.there is nothing in it.for example - for image it is showing "no preview available".cant i just open file without downloading it.

Comment: Did you check for errors from fopen()? Maybe you're not getting the filename right. You can't just open the file. You put the file on the server by uploading, you have to download to get it back. You can't just open files, because the files are on the server, not your PC. If that's not true, then you haven't explained things clearly enough.

Comment: as i have already mentioned that i am working on my laptop.i am trying to open a file saved in local drive.the function i require through php is that i just need to open a file after clicking a hyperlink to that file.If its not possible through php can u suggest some other way(interacting with mysql database).

Comment: If they're on your local drive, then I think your original code should work. You just have the wrong kind of quote in your HREF. It should be a regular quote, not backquote. `<?php echo "<a href='file:///C|/Inetpub/wwwroot/help.gif' >hi</a>";?>`

Comment: hmmm..but href='file:///C|/Inetpub/wwwroot/help.gif' >hi</a>";?> not working.nothing happens when i click hyperlink.is there anything regarding browser settings need to change???

Comment: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script  type="text/javascript">
function OpenPopup (c) {
window.open(c,'window',
'width=480,height=480,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
}
</script>
<body>
<p>hi</p>
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="OpenPopup(this.href)" >hiiii</a>
<?php 
$fpath=realpath('E:/settings.pdf');
echo $fpath;
echo "<a href=$fpath onclick=OpenPopup('E:/settings.pdf') >hiiii</a>";
?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: in the above  code its opening another window but its blank.but when i save the same file as html removing php tags,its working fine. please tell me whether u guys have understood my problem??i am searching about it all over.but couldnt find.

Comment: What happens if you just type the file: URL into the browser's location bar?

Comment: This webpage is not found
No webpage was found for the web address: file://url/
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.................this is the error i am getting.php is some how not reacting to the command "file://".I think i have to learn another server scripting

Comment: You weren't supposed to type 'file://url/' literally, you were supposed to put the actual path to your file, e.g. 'file:///C|/Inetpub/wwwroot/help.gif'. PHP isn't involved in accessing file: URLs, the browser just opens the file by itself.

Comment: actual path to the file is working fine.as i already mentioned that when i did copylink adress on right click of the link and paste in new window file is getting opened.but when i clicked on the link nothing happens

Comment: unfortunately same thing is happening with asp scripting also..ohhh i am gng mad.....

Comment: Can you post the PHP script you use for uploading? I think if I see that, I should be able to tell you how to write a similar script for downloading.

Comment: I Have give my php coding for uploading....please tell me some solution in which user selects an option from dropdown list and depending on the option a table should be displayed and in that table one column contains link to files.when user click on this link file should be opened without downloading(at least ask user what to do save or open)...

Comment: i am really sorry to bother you because my background is not comp science.I have uploaded my original download file also.i didnot understand where i have to incorporate the code given by you....sorry once again

Comment: Change `"<a href= $path>"` to `"<a href='download.php?name=$row[filename]'>"`.

Comment: what is the significance of the above code?whats happening when executed above line?

Comment: i am sorry to say this but above code line is stil not working.when i clicked on  the link it is giving errors as if my form elements are undefined...

Comment: Sorry, I made a small mistake, the link should be `?file=$row[filename]`, not `?name=$row[filename]`, since the script uses `$_GET['file']`. But if you can't debug a simple error like this, I think you may be in over your head.

Comment: i debugged it and i already tried the code you mentioned.you see i am not any programmer or software professional.I am a core electrical engineer.that's why may be these things seem to be simple for you but not for me.

Comment: actually when i am clicking the link it is accessing the file download.php and the error id that form variables i have used are not recognised,they are being treated as undefined. i have witten two codes for my page.first one contains only forms and action directs to the page (download.php).if i execute download.php directly again "form variable are undefined" error will come.Thats why i asked you how this line "?file=$row[filename]" works.This webpage was my extra assignment and i am still learning php,html coding and thats why i am asking basic questions

Comment: `<a href='download.php?file=$row[filename]'>` means that when you click on this link it will run the download.php script, and put the filename in `$_GET['file']`. The download.php script in my answer uses that to find the file that was previously uploaded, and send it back to the user.  In general, clicking on a link to `scriptname.php?var1=val&var2=val&...` is like submitting a form with fields `var1`, `var2`, etc. that uses `method="GET"`.